How to define new values and sort by those values when combining a list with itself?
I have a pandas dataframe like follows,
+------------+-------------------+---------+--------+----------+
| process_no | process_durations | columns | orders | customer |
+------------+-------------------+---------+--------+----------+
| 0          | 3                 | [0]     | [3109] | [0]      |
+------------+-------------------+---------+--------+----------+
| 1          | 100               | [11]    | [5855] | [0]      |
+------------+-------------------+---------+--------+----------+
| 2          | 81                | [8]     | [5304] | [0]      |
+------------+-------------------+---------+--------+----------+

I want to combine this dataframe with itself then, get the total length for orders, the length of unique values for columns, and the list of unique values for customers. Then, I want to sort in descending for the orders length and ascending for the columns length. But I should also keep the original version of the combination. For this situation, I did the following,
from itertools import combinations
from operator import itemgetter

data = pd.DataFrame({
     'process_no': [0, 1, 2],
     'process_durations': [3, 100, 81],
     'columns': [[0], [11], [8]],
     'orders': [[3109], [5855], [5304]],
     'customer': [[0], [0], [0]]
})

vals = data.values.tolist()
cross_combine = list(combinations(vals, r=2))

sorted_cross_combine = sorted(
    [
        (
            x,
            -(len(x[0][3]) + len(x[1][3])),
            len(set(x[0][2] + x[1][2])),
            list(set(x[0][4] + x[1][4]))
        )
        for x in cross_combine
    ],
    key=itemgetter(1, 2)
)
print(sorted_cross_combine)

[(([0, 3, [0], [3109], [0]], [1, 100, [11], [5855], [0]]), -2, 2, [0]),
 (([0, 3, [0], [3109], [0]], [2, 81, [8], [5304], [0]]), -2, 2, [0]),
 (([1, 100, [11], [5855], [0]], [2, 81, [8], [5304], [0]]), -2, 2, [0])]

And here is the my example output if you wanna choose do it with pandas,
+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+-------------+--------------+-----------+
| x1                          | x2                          |order_length |column_length | customers |
+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+-------------+--------------+-----------+
| [0, 3, [0], [3109], [0]]    | [1, 100, [11], [5855], [0]] | -2          | 2            | [0]       |
+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+-------------+--------------+-----------+
| [0, 3, [0], [3109], [0]]    | [2, 81, [8], [5304], [0]]   | -2          | 2            | [0]       |
+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+-------------+--------------+-----------+
| [1, 100, [11], [5855], [0]] | [2, 81, [8], [5304], [0]]   | -2          | 2            | [0]       |
+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+-------------+--------------+-----------+

If you look at columns x1 and x2,
orders   => [3109] and [5855]
columns  => [0] and [11]
customer => [0] and [0]

order_length  => -len([3109] + [5855])
column_length => len(set([0] + [1]))
customers     => list(set([0] + [0]))

What I want to ask is,
Can I do this while the combine process is still taking place, provided that it is more effective? For example, I know there is no such function, but I imagine something like this,
def calc(x, y):
    return (
        x + y,
        -(len(x[3]) + len(y[3])),
        len(set(x[2] + y[2])),
        list(set(x[4] + y[4]))
    )

cross_combine = list(combinations(vals, r=2, func=calc))

Or is there a way I can make the whole process more effective? The process of creating the sorted_cross_combine value takes about 20 seconds for a vals list with approximately 6500 elements.
You can download example data from the link. You need to cast data type as follows,
import ast

data = pd.read_csv('a.csv')

for col in ['columns', 'orders', 'customer']:
    data[col] = data[col].apply(ast.literal_eval)

Thanks in advance.

can you provide your expected input / output dataframes.

You can see my input and expected output in the code block. sorted_cross_combine is my expected output. However, the data type is not necessarily a list, it can be a data frame for example.

your example is unclear. You want to aggregate data in the dataframe, and then output a dataframe. So what should the resulting dataframe look like?

@iBeMeltin I've added my expected output if you wanna do it with pandas.

These two phrases are not clear.  What do you mean by "length of unique values for columns" (is it three or 14k+?)?, and the "list of unique values for customers" (is it one here?)?

@DavidCollins Did you examine expected output? You can see order_count, column_count and customers in the expected output.

I am also confused, - length is not the same as count, you have different requests in the example and in your text.
Count: how many values you have in the column. Unique vals can be counted separately...
Length - amount of symbols you have in the string.
So please clarify your request.
Also, would be nice to know the logic of "combine" you want to apply... Random unique values only or else?
Your code runs slow as you iterate each value/row, and you do not apply vectorized approach pandas has and looks like no one is able to advise  as no one see the logic behind.

@NoobVB I've updated my question, also you can check itertools.combinations for combine.

The sample of data you provided contains only 1 customer for all the records. If we suppose that there are more then one customer, would it be correct to assume that at least each single record has only one value in the customer field, sort of [0] or [1, 1] or [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], but never [0, 1] or [0, 0, 1, 0, 1] etc.?

General ideas
First of all, the answer to the question, whether you can calculate additional data during the combination process, is "Yes, you can". Just keep cross_combine as a generator, not list, until the main calculation,  i.e. cross_combine = combinations(vals, r=2). But it's unlikely to do you any good. IMO the main issues in this case are:

The python objects inside of your data, i.e. lists in each record. This leads not only to additional memory overhead, but also to inefficient vector computations.

Multiple duplication of data, potentially eating up all available memory. Let's make a rough estimate: 6500 records end up in about 20 million pairwise combinations, plus 5 columns taken twice and 3 additional ones, presumably 8 bytes for each cell - all of this together takes up about 2 gigabytes. With intermediate copies in the computation chain, this easily turns into 6-8G, especially when we start creating new sets and lists.


So I would get rid of objects in cells and reduce data duplication by focusing on the minimum key information needed.
Possible solution
At first, I'd use the pyjanitor's conditional_join method instead of combinations from itertools (optionally with numba to make it work faster if possible). And I would start by pairing only the record IDs stored in "process_no", sort of:
base = df[['process_no']].conditional_join(df['process_no'], ('process_no', 'process_no', '<'))

To calculate "order_length", we can map "orders" with len before joining, and sum left and right lengths after that:
base = df[['process_no']].assign(orders=df['orders'].map(len))
base = base.conditional_join(base, ('process_no', 'process_no', '<'))
base = base.assign(order_length=base.left.orders + base.right.orders)

Now the tricky part. The sample data looks like this:



process_no
process_durations
columns
orders
customer




315
150
[26, 26]
[3957, 3974]
[0, 0]


316
148
[24, 24, 24, 24]
[3837, 3841, 3873, 4103]
[0, 0, 0, 0]


317
154
[29, 29, 29]
[3853, 2998, 4245]
[0, 0, 0]



If we can assume that each process describes a set of orders made by a single customer on a single column, then we can replace associated lists with their single representatives. And the question of expected "column_length" and "customers" values can be replaced by whether or not columns and customers associated with a pair of processes are equal, sort of:
proc_column = df.set_index('process_no')['columns'].str[0]
base = (
    base
    .join(proc_column.rename('left_column'), on='left_process_no')
    .join(proc_column.rename('right_column'), on='right_process_no')
    .assign(column_length=lambda x: 1 + x.left_column != x.right_column)
    .drop(columns=['left_column', 'right_column'])
)

But what if a process can be associated with several different columns and customers? Well, let's try to eliminate lists from the cells. From the original data sample, we can assume that the number of different values in "columns" is limited by 30 items for almost 6500 records. As for unique customers, there's only one value for all records. So let's suppose that the number of unique columns and customers does not exceed 64 (the number of bits in the longest integer). In this case, we can replace each value with a unique power of 2 and use the bitwise logical OR operator in place of the union of sets like this:
import pandas, janitor, numpy

df = pandas.read_csv('data.csv', dtype=str).map(eval)

column_mapping = {
    column: 2**code 
    for code, column in enumerate(df['columns'].explode().unique())
}

base = (
    df.explode('columns')
    .astype({'columns': int})
    .replace({'columns': column_mapping})
    .groupby('process_no')
    .agg({'columns': numpy.bitwise_or.reduce})
    .reset_index()
)

base = base.conditional_join(base, ('process_no', 'process_no', '<'))
base['column_length'] = base[('left', 'columns')] | base[('right', 'columns')]
base['column_length'] = base['column_length'].map(int.bit_count)

If the number of unique values in lists are bigger than 64, then we could try to work with bytes.
Code to experiment with
Case with a unique customer and column for each process
import pandas as pd
import janitor
from itertools import product

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', dtype=str).map(eval)

base = df[['process_no']].assign(
    orders = df['orders'].map(len),
    column = df['columns'].str[0],
    customer = df['customer'].str[0],
)

base = base.conditional_join(base, ('process_no', 'process_no', '<'))

base = base.assign(
    order_length = base.left.orders + base.right.orders,
    column_length = 1 + (base.left.column != base.right.column),
    is_equal_customer = base.left.customer == base.right.customer
)

base.drop(columns=product(['left','right'], ['orders','column','customer']), inplace=True)
base.columns = base.columns.droplevel(1)

>>> print(base.sort_values(['order_length', 'column_length'], ascending=[False, True]))
          left  right  order_length  column_length  is_equal_customer
1967682    314    316             9              2               True
1943238    310    314             8              2               True
1955461    312    314             8              2               True
1967683    314    317             8              2               True
1937125    309    314             7              2               True
...        ...    ...           ...            ...                ...
20630635  6414   6419             2              2               True
20630636  6414   6420             2              2               True
20630637  6414   6421             2              2               True
20630638  6414   6422             2              2               True
20630639  6414   6423             2              2               True

Сase with multiple clients/columns for each process, but limited diversity overall
import pandas as pd
import janitor
from numpy import bitwise_or
from itertools import product
from io import StringIO


raw_data = '''process_no,process_durations,columns,orders,customer
0,3,[0],[3109],[0]
1,100,[11],[5855],[1]
2,81,[8],[5304],[0]
309,141,"[18, 19]","[1764, 2077]","[0, 0]"
310,145,"[21, 19, 21]","[2280, 78, 2066]","[1, 0, 3]"
312,153,"[27, 27, 18]","[3076, 3567, 3999]","[0, 0, 2]"
314,143,"[17, 19, 27, 17, 17]","[5656, 6040, 6253, 5419, 5748]","[0, 1, 1, 0, 5]"
315,150,"[26, 26]","[3957, 3974]","[1, 0]"
316,148,"[24, 27, 24, 24]","[3837, 3841, 3873, 4103]","[0, 1, 2, 0]"
317,154,"[29, 27, 24]","[3853, 2998, 4245]","[0, 1, 0]"
'''

raw_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(raw_data), dtype=str).map(eval)
df = (
    raw_df
    .assign(orders=lambda x: x['orders'].map(len))
    .explode(['columns', 'customer'])
    .astype({'columns': int, 'customer': int})
)
column_mapping = {
    column: 2**code 
    for code, column in enumerate(df['columns'].unique())
}
customer_mapping = {
    customer: 2**code 
    for code, customer in enumerate(df['customer'].unique())
}
df = df.replace({
    'columns': column_mapping, 
    'customer': customer_mapping
})
df = df.groupby('process_no').agg({
       'columns': bitwise_or.reduce,
       'orders': 'first',
       'customer': bitwise_or.reduce
}).reset_index()

base = df.conditional_join(df, ('process_no', 'process_no', '<'))

base['orders_length'] = base.left.orders + base.right.orders
base['column_length'] = base.left['columns'] | base.right['columns']
base['column_length'] = base['column_length'].map(int.bit_count)
base['customers'] = base.left.customer | base.right.customer
base['customers'] = base['customers'].map(
    lambda x: [customer for customer, code in customer_mapping.items() if code & x])

base.drop(columns=product(['left', 'right'], ['columns', 'orders', 'customer']), 
          inplace=True)
base.columns = base.columns.droplevel(1)
base.sort_values(['orders_length', 'column_length'], 
                 ascending=[False, True], 
                 inplace=True)

>>> print(out.head())
    left  right  orders_length  column_length     customers
40   314    316              9              4  [0, 1, 2, 5]
31   310    314              8              4  [0, 1, 3, 5]
35   312    314              8              4  [0, 1, 2, 5]
41   314    317              8              5     [0, 1, 5]
37   312    316              7              3     [0, 1, 2]

